# Show that $f$ is a measurable function if $f$ is bounded

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $m(E)=0$. Show that if $f$ is a bounded function on E, then $f$ is measurable, and the Lebesgue integral is zero.
I was thinking of using this theorem that state that $\int f =0 $ iff $f=0$ that would means that $f$ is the zero function, which i don't think i can assume. any idea thanks

Comment: It's ambigus. You want to show that $f$ is measurable on all $\mathbb R$ or on $E$ only ?

Comment: It is in any case false that $\int f = 0$ implies $f=0$ (though I will grant you the converse).  With Lebesgue measure, any subset of a null set $E$ (set of measure zero) is again of measure zero.  That would be my approach.

Comment: yeah, i was thinking that to but i knew that thinking was wrong that is one of the reason i post it